# array parameter insert function for dbconnect with arraylist

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, arraylist, sql-insert

i have this main insert function in my dbconnect class. i want to use all form this function. and i called function but it is not working. what can i do ? where is my mistake?

This is my DBConnect class

```
public bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
            //on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Close connection
    public bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Insert statement
    public void Insert(string tablename , ArrayList [] values )
    {
        string val = "VALUES" + "(" ;
            for (int i=0; i<values.Length; i++  )
        {
            if (values.Length > 1)
                val += values[i] + ",";
            else val += values[i];
        }
        val += ")";
        string query = "INSERT INTO "+ tablename + val ;

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Here is the calling function when button has clicked. i think so i ' m not found what will the come here "????"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DBConnect conn = new DBConnect();
        conn.Insert("rezervationinformations", *????* );
    }
```

Comment: An array with the values you want to insert.

Comment: You will also need to change `"VALUES" + "(" ;` to `" VALUES" + "(" ;` so that their is a space between your table name and the keyword `VALUES`.

Comment: I know i have a syntax mistakes but i need function parameters on the button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are set on having to use an `ArrayList` this is how it should look.  An `ArrayList` is a list of arrays which might be causing issues.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DBConnect conn = new DBConnect();
    conn.Insert("rezervationinformations", 
    new ArrayList(new string[] {"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6"}) );
}
```

Otherwise just use a regular `string[]` array:

`public void Insert(string tablename , string[] values )`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DBConnect conn = new DBConnect();
    conn.Insert("rezervationinformations", 
    new string[] {"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6"}) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it. thank u for your anseer but i havea ExecuteNonQuery error

my function:

```
public void Insert(string tablename ,string[] values, string[] columns)
    {
        string val =  "VALUES"+"(";
        foreach (var value in values)
        {

            if (values.Length > 1)
                val += values + ",";
            if (values == null)
                val = "";
            else val += values;
        }
        val += ")";
        string col = "(";
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {

            if (columns.Length > 1)
                col += columns + ",";
            if (columns == null)
                col = "";
            else col += columns;
        }
        col += ")";
```

called function:

```
conn.Insert("rezervationinformations",  new string[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text }, new string[] { "FullName", "Phone", "Description" });
```

my query: return from the function

```
"INSERT INTO rezervationinformations(System.String[],System.String[]System.String[],System.String[]System.String[],System.String[])VALUES(System.String[],System.String[]System.String[],System.String[]System.String[],System.String[])"
```

Comment: Try `foreach (var value in values[0])` as I think you are using an `ArrayList` but only using 1 array.  Do the same with the columns `foreach (var column in columns[0])`